# What does the "=>" symbol do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was looking at a solution on Codewars and I'm confused by the "=>" symbol. I thought the filter method had to take a callback function and although I can see the logic behind what's happening, I have not seen the symbol used before and can't find any reference to it on the internet.

```
function move_zeros(arrNum, isRight = true) {
  let zeroes    = arrNum.filter(i => i === 0);
  let nonZeroes = arrNum.filter(i => i !== 0);

  return isRight ?
    nonZeroes.concat(zeroes) :
    zeroes.concat(nonZeroes);
}
```

Comment: Look up "fat arrow JavaScript"

Comment: See [*MDN Arrow Functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Note that *this* is set to the same value as the containing execution context.

Comment: @JanDvorak: JavaScript has arrow functions, but not "fat arrows".

Comment: @FelixKling Google "fat arrow Javascript" and you might change your mind :)

Comment: @SteveBennett: that doesn't mean we have to make the same mistake. The official term is "arrow function" and I'd say we just stick with that :)

Comment: @felix but, would you accept "fat arrow" as a general name for the symbol irrespective of the language it is in?